# Foundation 5 with IE8 completely inconsistent

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

Last week i launched a site live in production using Foundation 5. I have tried everything with this application using respond.js, htmlShiv.js and much more. I have made sure to include the shivs and respond.js after my css and for the most part it works however, the nav bar appears collapsed and expanded as someone would view through mobile. The site also looks completely different in IE8 compatibility mode even after I have included

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />.
```

Most users which will be hitting the application will be from school districts and they never update their browsers therefore, I need to support back to it.
Here is the nav bar in IE8 Compatibility Mode[image]

Here is the nav bar in IE8 without Compatability Mode.
[image]

Here is the nav bar in Chrome and this is how it is supposed to look like.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated as I have applied every solution possible out there by moving my respond and shivs around. Making sure im not using CDN's for my css or any of my js files. I am stumped why this inconsistent behavior exists.

Here is my code for the nav bar.

```
                <nav class="top-bar" id="top-bar" data-topbar>
                    <ul class="title-area">
                        <li class="name">
                            <div class="name-logo"><a href="http://10.51.10.42:8009/">EBi</a></div><!-- title on navigation -->
                        </li>
                        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
                        <a href="#"><em class="fa fa-bars"></em></a> </li>
                    </ul>

                    <section class="top-bar-section" id="menu"><!-- menu -->


                          <ul class="nav-bar-section">
                            
                            <li><div class="home"><a href="#header"><strong>EB</strong>i</a></div></li>
                            <li><a href="#our-story">Our Story</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#educator-solutions">Educator Solutions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#our-team">Our Team</a></li>
                            <!--<li><a href="#lets-talk">Let's Talk</a></li>-->
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                            <!--<a href="#">--><li title="Soon EBi-AR.com will allow you to log in to your EBi account"><div class="login">Login</div><img src="images/logo/bubble2.png" style="padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:5px;"></li><!--</a>-->
                            
                        </ul>

                  </section><!-- .menu -->
                </nav>

        </div>
```

Here is my head with the references.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

        <meta name="description" content="" />

        <!-- Google Fonts -->

                <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calligraffitti' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro:900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/component.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/theme.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>


        <!-- JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./stylesheets/ie8.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./stylesheets/IE.css">
         <script src="./js/htmlShiv.js"></script>
         <script src="./js/respond.js"></script>
         <script src="./js/ie8-head.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/nwmatcher.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/selectivizr.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/PIE.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


    </head>
```

I am including scripts in the bottom of my webpage as well.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/masonry.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/classie.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/AnimOnScroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/headroom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/toucheffects.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/jquery.fitvid.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/froogaloop.js"></script>

        <!--fixes IE not formatting content correctly-->
        <script src="js/rem.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--.fixes IE not formatting content correctly-->


        <!--[if IE 9]>
            <script src="./js/ie8.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
```

If there is anything sticking out to anyone which is quite noticeable i would really appreciate the guidance as I have been stumped on supporting back to IE8 corrrectly.

Comment: Have a look here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/compatibility.html Foundation 5 is not ment to support IE8. Maybe this is of help for you anyways: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/241-foundation-5-and-ie8

Comment: I have tried that second link before coming here with no luck at all. Wish it was that easy.

Comment: There is no such thing as `<!--[if lt IE 10]>`. IE 10+ does not support conditional comments. I really don't know what happens if IE 9 tries to handle that. Try changin it to `<!--[if lt IE 9]>`. Also, doesn't Foundtation 5 _require_ jQuery 2.0+?

Comment: Even if 10 doesnt support the conditional comments, 8 is still rendering the stylesheets and js files. So the conditional being addressed is out of scope. It seems that I am using version 2.0 with the script tag at the bottom of my document. I inspected my sources as well and jquery 2.0 is being used. Need another suggestion.

Comment: This is the best fix I've found: http://www.kycosoftware.com/blog/getting-foundation-5-to-work-in-ie8

Answer (score 2):

Foudation doesn't support Internet Explorer 8.

Furthermore IE8 in compatibility mode behaves like IE7 which has a non-standard box model.

Comment: Yes i see that. There are workarounds for it and i am looking for people who understand how to work around IE8 with foundation.